Get ClickOnce Deployment Version in .Net (Core/Standard) Version 8 or 9
With the old .Net Framework you could get the click-once deployment version using the following code:
System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
This library does not exist in .Net Standard (at least the current versions 8 and 9). Is there an alternate way to get that information?

maybe check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/access-clickonce-deployment-properties-dotnet?view=vs-2022  (I guess the launcher sets environment variables... in this case the environment is the core run-time)

Thanks, this works perfectly.
string version = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClickOnce_CurrentVersion");

@Jeff you should add that as an answer
